# Mysql query for multiple values for the same id

Tags: php, mysql

I hope someone can help me with a mysql statement. In the end I need it this way for example:  (will be json encoded later).

`{"meta_value": "Breitensteinstr 82031"} //street and plz`

`{"meta_value": "Danziger Str 65307"} //street and plz`

`{"meta_value": "71032"} //no street on this one`

I can get the single values by doing

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `stroma_commentmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'plz' or meta_key = 'street';
```

but now I'm stuck.

How can I get both values for the same comment_id in the same table? My brain can't get the connections.

Screen of the DB:

[image]

Comment: add the `comment_id` to the `WHERE` clause with an `AND` and using a subquery.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The example output you want just shows the meta_value key containing the keys. But you already know the keys.. I'm sure this is a mistake in the question, but it helps to get the question right when wanting help.

Comment: You also never mentioned "which" id; you have 2 columns bearing the prefix. You have an answer below, ask them if you're not going to respond to comments or you just "took off" somewhere. I already told you what to do.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT  group_concat( 
      meta_value 
         ORDER BY  
         meta_key DESC  
         SEPARATOR " "  ) as meta_value 
  FROM `stroma_commentmeta` 
  WHERE meta_key = 'plz' or meta_key = 'street' 
  GROUP BY comment_id ;
```

this comes with some limitations :

- there should be a unique on meta_key and comment_id
- length is (defaultly) limited to 1024 chars (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

alternatively just join them together ...

```
SELECT  straight_join concat( s.meta_value, " " , p.meta_value  ) as    meta_value  
FROM `stroma_commentmeta` p
JOIN `stroma_commentmeta` s on s.comment_id=p.comment_id and s.meta_key = 'street'
  WHERE p.meta_key = 'plz' ;
```

Comment: glad it hepled, which one you used? .. the second should be faster , the first is somethingto show off ;) and learn new mysql features

Comment: I used the first one, the second one wasn't even there when I tried it. I'm jealous of you guys doing these sql queries by heart in minutes. Thanks again.